# Filter by distinct column values from selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Trying to get a value box output where it is only summing a column (Sold) based on the selections I would make to 2 other columns. My idea was to filter the data down based on my selection, then summarize the remaining rows by the Sold column. Code here:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

df <- 
  data.frame(Car_Col = c("Red","Blue","Red","Black","White","Black","Black","White","Red","Blue"),
             Car_Type = c("E","G","D","G","G","D","G","D","E","G"),
             Sold = (c(1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      selectInput(
      inputId = "x",
      label = "Select variable",
      choices = c(unique(df$Car_Col)),
    )),
    selectInput(
      inputId = "x2",
      label = "Select variable",
      choices = c(unique(df$Car_Type))
    ),
    valueBoxOutput("box1"),
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
    output$box1 <- renderValueBox({
    df %>% 
        filter(Car_Col == .data[[input$x]]) %>% 
        filter(Car_Type == .data[[input$x2]]) %>% 
        summarise(Number_Sold = sum(Sold)) %>% 
        pull(Number_Sold) %>% 
        valueBox(subtitle = "Number of sales")
        })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This spits back the error;

```
Warning: Error in filter: Problem while
computing `..1 = Car_Col ==
.data[["Red"]]`.
Caused by error in `.data[["Red"]]`:
! Column `Red` not
  found in `.data`.
```

Now I believe that the way I've done it above is essentially telling the filter to look for a column called whatever I've selected as an input, which are the distinct values so column name is coming up empty. I understand why I'm wrong but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

End goal would be, for instance from the code above, to be able to select say

```
Car_Col = Red
Car_Type = E

valueBoxOutput would then give 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did very little to your code, but this for me works, is this what you were looking for? One, I removed the `c()` from the `choices = c(unique(...))` since for me at least, it was coercing them into numbers instead of characters. And two, in the filter I removed the `.data[[]]`. Hopefully this helps!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

df <- 
  data.frame(Car_Col = c("Red","Blue","Red","Black","White","Black","Black","White","Red","Blue"),
             Car_Type = c("E","G","D","G","G","D","G","D","E","G"),
             Sold = (c(1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "x",
        label = "Select variable",
        choices = unique(df$Car_Col),
      )),
    selectInput(
      inputId = "x2",
      label = "Select variable",
      choices = unique(df$Car_Type)
    ),
    valueBoxOutput("box1"),
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$box1 <- renderValueBox({
    df %>% 
      filter(Car_Col == input$x) %>% 
      filter(Car_Type == input$x2) %>% 
      summarise(Number_Sold = sum(Sold)) %>% 
      pull(Number_Sold) %>% 
      valueBox(subtitle = "Number of sales")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Silent! This did work, thank you. Would you mind helping me understand as to why? the ```c()``` in ```choices=c(...``` wasn't the issue, in fact the code runs just by removing ```.data[[]]``` from the input$x/x2. I'm unsure as to why this is, I'm using .data[[]] in different ways to drag in many reactive inputs so would be good to understand why that is making it break here if you have any insight!

Comment: To be honest, I have pretty limited knowledge on that. I was referred to this page once which talks about it: https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html#action-tidy I think it's something to do with what you are doing with the input. In this case, you are just looking for a string "red" or whatever, so the ```.data[[]]``` isn't necessary because you are using the string as is. But if you were selecting a column based on the input then it needs to be evaluated with that argument, i.e. ```df%>%select(.data[[input$x]])```. Hopefully that's correct and helps lol